# My code broke with ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape when using yaho data reader

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, pandas-datareader

The code worked just fine but now it gives me this error after these lines:

```
end = dt.datetime.now()
start = dt.date(end.year - 3, end.month, end.day)
prices = reader.get_data_yahoo(tickers,start,end)['Adj Close']
```

I tried upgrading packages and everything but it didn't help.The code doesn't work now even for the data I previously successfully downloaded and analysied via it.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 end = dt.datetime.now()
      2 start = dt.date(end.year - 3, end.month, end.day)
----> 3 prices = reader.get_data_yahoo(tickers,start,end)['Adj Close']

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py:80, in get_data_yahoo(*args, **kwargs)
     79 def get_data_yahoo(*args, **kwargs):
---> 80     return YahooDailyReader(*args, **kwargs).read()

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py:256, in _DailyBaseReader.read(self)
    254 # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    255 elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):
--> 256     df = self._dl_mult_symbols(self.symbols.index)
    257 else:
    258     df = self._dl_mult_symbols(self.symbols)

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py:285, in _DailyBaseReader._dl_mult_symbols(self, symbols)
    283         stocks[sym] = df_na
    284 if PANDAS_0230:
--> 285     result = concat(stocks, sort=True).unstack(level=0)
    286 else:
    287     result = concat(stocks).unstack(level=0)

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:8413, in DataFrame.unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   8351 """
   8352 Pivot a level of the (necessarily hierarchical) index labels.
   8353 
   (...)
   8409 dtype: float64
   8410 """
   8411 from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import unstack
-> 8413 result = unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   8415 return result.__finalize__(self, method="unstack")

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py:478, in unstack(obj, level, fill_value)
    476 if isinstance(obj, DataFrame):
    477     if isinstance(obj.index, MultiIndex):
--> 478         return _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value=fill_value)
    479     else:
    480         return obj.T.stack(dropna=False)

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py:501, in _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value)
    499 def _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value=None):
    500     if not obj._can_fast_transpose:
--> 501         unstacker = _Unstacker(obj.index, level=level)
    502         mgr = obj._mgr.unstack(unstacker, fill_value=fill_value)
    503         return obj._constructor(mgr)

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py:140, in _Unstacker.__init__(self, index, level, constructor)
    133 if num_cells > np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
    134     warnings.warn(
    135         f"The following operation may generate {num_cells} cells "
    136         f"in the resulting pandas object.",
    137         PerformanceWarning,
    138     )
--> 140 self._make_selectors()

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py:192, in _Unstacker._make_selectors(self)
    189 mask.put(selector, True)
    191 if mask.sum() < len(self.index):
--> 192     raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape")
    194 self.group_index = comp_index
    195 self.mask = mask

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, however I wonder, whether it is possible to use the previous version of Pandas so that API from yaho commensurates with it. Or perhaps, there could be other solutions that enable the intial version of code to operate properly

Answer (score 1):

I know it can be frustrating but for the moment you have to read each ticker individually. The API is probably broken since the lastest versions of Pandas:

```
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']
end = dt.datetime.now()
start = dt.date(end.year - 3, end.month, end.day)

data = {}
for ticker in tickers:
    data[ticker] = reader.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)['Adj Close']
prices = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> prices
                  AAPL        MSFT
Date                              
2019-03-11   43.548748  109.345795
2019-03-12   44.038033  110.111404
2019-03-13   44.232773  110.964211
2019-03-14   44.724491  111.051437
2019-03-15   45.306278  112.330688
...                ...         ...
2022-03-07  159.300003  278.910004
2022-03-08  157.440002  275.850006
2022-03-09  162.949997  288.500000
2022-03-10  158.520004  285.589996
2022-03-10  158.520004  285.589996

[759 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same error, unfortunately this did not resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when the query is made on a Saturday or Sunday, since Yahoo Finance repeats the data for Friday twice.

You can check it by looking at the historical data in finance yahoo itself.

For a single stock can be solved with:

`data = data[~data.index.duplicated(keep='last')]`

But, when downloading info for a list of stocks, , the solution is proposed by iterating over said list and then concatenating the series to construct the df.

Then you can use the code above to remove the duplicate indexes.